# Initialize data structure in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to initialize this data structure:

```
  var array:ArrayBuffer[Map[Int,Int]] = ArrayBuffer()

  for ( i <- 0 to 10) {
    array(i) = Map()
  }
```

but I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ArrayBuffer` is empty, so you cannot set an element at index `i` to a new `Map` - index `i` is not a valid index if the `ArrayBuffer` is empty. Use this instead:

```
for (i <- 0 to 10) {
  array += Map()
}
```

Or this:

```
var array: ArrayBuffer[Map[Int, Int]] = ArrayBuffer.fill(10) { Map() }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Scala whenever you're using a mutable data structure, like the ArrayBuffer, you should ask yourself if you really really need it.
If you really need it, the mutable structure should not leave the scope of the method so it is not exposed to other parts of the program because that could cause concurrency issue.

The good thing of Scala is that by default it uses immutable data structures.

Instead of using a ArrayBuffer, I would rather use this to create a traversable structure with maps:

```
for {
  i <- 0 to 10
} yield Map.empty[Int, Int]
```

This will return a Vector[Map[Int, Int]] which can still be used to access elements at a specific index, just like an array, and Vector has an 'update' method to update an element at a specific index, but ... it returns a new immutable Vector!