# Setting values in ArrayBuffer by index in Scala

Tags: scala

I need to add to an array two strings, omitting the first occurrence:

```
  val strings = ArrayBuffer[String]()

  strings(1) = "abc1"
  strings(2) = "abc2"
```

But I'm getting

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize data structure in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919895/initialize-data-structure-in-scala)

Comment: This is more or less the same question as [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919895/initialize-data-structure-in-scala). You first need to add elements to the `ArrayBuffer` before you can modify the elements at specific indices.

Comment: but I can't add elements with `+=` as I need to set them with an index

Comment: If you know how big your array needs to be (which the need to use an index suggests), then use an Array of the right size, not an ArrayBuffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ArrayBuffer` is empty, so you cannot set an element at index `i` to a new `String` - index `i` is not a valid index if the `ArrayBuffer` is empty. First make sure the elements exist in the `ArrayBuffer` by adding them:

```
val strings = ArrayBuffer[String]()

strings += "abc1"
strings += "abc2"
```

Now the `ArrayBuffer` has two elements and you can modify them if you want. Note that indices start at 0, not at 1.

```
strings(0) = "something else"
strings(1) = "hello world"
```

If you want to pre-fill the `ArrayBuffer` you can for example use `fill`, as I showed you in my answer to your previous question.

```
// Fill with 10 empty strings (creates 10 elements in the ArrayBuffer)
val strings = ArrayBuffer.fill(10) { "" }

// Now you can set them (valid indices are 0...9)
strings(0) = "abc1"
strings(1) = "abc2"
```

Alternatively, use a `Map` instead of an `ArrayBuffer`, where the keys of your map are numbers and the values are strings.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

val strings: Map[Int, String] = Map()

strings(1) = "abc1"
strings(2) = "abc2"
```

Comment: There's no way to set the occurrences by index?

Comment: @ps0604 What do you mean? If you use an `ArrayBuffer`, then the element at the specified index must exist before you can modify it. See also my alternative solution with a `Map`.